# How to get all row values tabulator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabulator

I have editable table using tabulator.

Everything is ok, but the problem is I can't get all row value when click "save button"

What I'm trying is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var tabledata = [
  {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
  {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
  {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
  {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
  {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];
 
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height:205,
  data:tabledata,
  layout:"fitColumns",
  columns:[
   {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
   {title:"Age", field:"age", visible: false},
   {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
   {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
  ],
  footerElement:"<button id='save' class='pull-left' title='Save'>Save</button> ",
});

 $(document).on("click", "#save", function(){
   /* var data = $("#example-table").tabulator("getData"); */
   var data = $('#example-table').getData();
        console.log('save clicked');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.1.5/js/jquery_wrapper.js"></script>


<div id="example-table"></div>
```

When running it shows error

> TypeError: $.widget is not a function

When I try using:

```
var data = $("#example-table").tabulator("getData");
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).tabulator is not a function

when using:

```
var data = $('#example-table').getData();
```

the error is:

> TypeError: $(...).getData is not a function

When I try to define the table using this method:

```
$("#example-table").tabulator({ //table setup options });
```

it's not showing anything (blank).

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Or give me the reference how to get all row values?

You can try in jsfiddle too, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dianeryanto/fytghe7s/)

Comment: The jsfiddle link shows nothing on the UI.

Comment: you can check again sir, forget to update, sorry @PrashantZombade

Comment: No. The UI is still blank.

Comment: omg, already updated sir. sorry @PrashantZombade

Comment: Yes, it is there now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for version 4.5+:**

In version 4.5+ there is a function that lets you find the table with a query selector when the table variable is not accessible.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/options#find-table

```
const table = Tabulator.prototype.findTable('#example-table')[0];
const data = table.getData();
```

**Original answer:**

The issue is because you are declaring the table variable inside a function, so its scope is limited.

If you declare it in the global scope, and then assign it inside the function it will then be accessible everywhere.

```
//global scope
var table

//assign inside table - notice no "var"
function generateGrid(){
    table = new Tabulator("#example-table", { ....
}

//you can then use it everywhere
var data = table.getData();
```

Comment: This solves the global problem I was having. I was redeclaring table variable every time. Oli, we love you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of, `var data = $('#example-table').getData();`

Use, `var data = table.getData();`

what you are doing is chaining `getData()` on jQuery function but you have to implement `getData()` on Tabulator table instance which is `var table` which you created above.

Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: You are using the new 4.0 method of instantiating the table, which does not use jQuery which is why you cant access it by selector later on

Comment: Your answer is work, but my problem is i'm declare my table inside function like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dianeryanto/06dj9h8g/), can you tell me how to get value when im declare the table inside function?? cc: @OliFolkerd

Answer (score 1):

Based on my last comment who declared the table inside function.

This is my way to get specific value when click save button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function generateGrid(){
  var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
     height:205,
     data:tabledata,
     layout:"fitColumns",
     columns:[
       {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
       {title:"Age", field:"age", visible: false},
       {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", editor:"input", formatter:
         function (row, formatterParams){
            let rowId = row.getData().id;
            let color = row.getData().col;
            
            return '<input type="text" class="txtAU" name="txtAU" id="txtAU'+rowId+'" value="' + color +'"/>';
            }
       },
       {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
     ],
     footerElement:"<button id='save' class='pull-left' title='Save'>Save</button> ",
});
}
 
  $(document).on("click", "#view", function(){
   generateGrid();
   $('#example-table').show();
  });
  
 $(document).on("click", "#save", function(){
  
    var data_ = "";
    var i = 1;
    $("input[name='txtAU']").each(function(){
        data_=data_+$(this).val()+";";
        i++;
    });
    console.log(data_);
    console.log('save clicked');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>



<button id='view' class='pull-left' title='Save'>Show Table</button> 

<div id="example-table" style="display:none"></div>
```

And if you looking get the all value and declared table like usually, you can use

> var data = table.getData();

like Gaurav's answer. Thankyou, hope this help someone.